# How to make works cordova-based app with ProGuard

Tags: cordova, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

Im trying to build cordova-based app with obfuscation enabled.
IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation version is 7.1.0.00.20151227-1730.

My steps:
 - create new classic `mfp` project (used as environment runtime)
 - create new `mfp cordova` project with Android Env (used as client app)
 - `push` new client app to environment
 - uncomment `proguard.config` option in `project.properties`
 - add proper keystore configuration in `project.properties`
 - configure app for release
 - run `ant release` as usual

Output:
I get huge amount of warnings
`[proguard] Note: duplicate definition of program class ...`

Then build failes
`[proguard] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
     [proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
     [proguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
     [proguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option
     [proguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
     BUILD FAILED`

And this is on newly created project. Nothing changed. Just added keystore.

How should I properly configure ProGuard?

Comment: While you generated the Cordova project with MFP, you built a Cordova project (unlike with Hybrid apps). This question is for Cordova. You should provide your project probably.

Comment: use cordova-plugin-proguard, see description in my post https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case has to do with classes that have **package private** access modifiers on fields or methods. These get obfuscated by default. Thus the warning "Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members."

As suggested you could use -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers in proguard-project.txt (see below).
For details on this and other config parameters, check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html

Change android/proguard configuration in proguard-project.txt (see http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements)